# css3 resetting the translate immediately before using it again in a transition

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to animate this scrolling function where links are transitioned out of the screen by having a translate y value of 100%. The problem I'm facing is that when I scroll up I need to reset the 100% back to a percentage higher off the screen, for example 11%. I want to transition from 11% to 24%, however it ends up going from 100% straight to 24%. Is there any way to "reset" or do two css changes instantaneously?

http://jsfiddle.net/NQeUr/2/

```
<div id="container">
<div class="experiment" style="-webkit-transform:translate(0px,100%);"> test </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$(".experiment").css({"-webkit-transition":"0s","-webkit-transform":"translate(0px,11%)"});
$(".experiment").css({"-webkit-transition":"2s","-webkit-transform":"translate(0px,24%)"});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think the two transitions are happening too quickly, so wrapping the second transition in a setTimeout function works. For example:

```
setTimeout(function () { $(".experiment:eq("+i+")").css({"-webkit-transition":""+speed[id]+"s","-webkit-transform":"translate(0px,"+percent+"%)"}); });
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can get the position of your scroll using jquery and then you can change the css as you doing here

```
$(".experiment").css({"-webkit-transition":"0s","-webkit-transform":"translate(0px,11%)"});
```

Comment: yes, but that doesn't work as I want to transition to 24% immediately after setting it to 11%.